# Is there a way to run .frame.origin.y before the auto layout

Tags: xcode, swift3, ios-autolayout

I im using autolayout and have aligned text fields to each-other. But now that the whole app is ready, there is a special case where eveything will be hidden except ONE text field. So Im moving this text field up with .frame.origin.y

The problem is that this text field now appears in the middle for a second, because autolauout does its job first. I dont want to turn OFF autolayout entirely, i just want to be able to so SOMEHTING before autolauout.

I tried viewdidappear and the beginning of viewdidload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code into `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. That is the moment when autolayout is applied. Use a condition to make sure that your code runs only under the right conditions, because `viewDidLayoutSubviews` can be called many times during the course of your app's lifetime, and most of those times you will not want it to do anything special.

Be aware that changing the `frame.origin.y` is going to cause a conflict with your autolayout constraints. The correct way to do this sort of thing is to change the *constraints*. You will probably need to configure an outlet to the desired constraint so that you can refer to it in code; that way, you can just change that constraint's `constant`.

Comment: Thanx... That's what i was looking for. Had to improvise here.